# Save Individual Torrents with Libtorrent save_state()?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, libtorrent

I'm currently working with [Ragnar](https://github.com/libragnar/ragnar) which is a CLI Libtorrent wrapper.

I've hit a brick wall. Perhaps it's an implementation flaw of the wrapper I'm using, or I've simply misunderstood the Libtorrent API documentation, but I can't figure out how to properly save/load the current Session state data.

My current goal, as I can best state it, is to save all `torrent_handles` in the current session, so that when I next run the torrent client I am working on, I can load them automatically on startup and resume downloading/seeding.

I'm still unsure if I should do this by saving the Session state or not. As per the [API documentation's](http://libtorrent.org/manual.html#load-state-save-state) wording:

> The flags arguments passed in to save_state can be used to filter which parts of the session state to save. By default, all state is saved (except for the individual torrents).

But I can see no flag which pertains to `individual torrents`:

```
enum save_state_flags_t
{
        save_settings =     0x001,
        save_dht_settings = 0x002,
        save_dht_state =    0x004,
        save_proxy =        0x008,
        save_i2p_proxy =    0x010,
        save_encryption_settings = 0x020,
        save_as_map =       0x040,
        save_feeds =        0x080
};
```

Also, the wrapper is currently hard coded to not accept these flags:

```
cli::array<byte>^ Session::SaveState()
{
    libtorrent::entry entry;
    this->_session->save_state(entry);

    return Utils::GetByteArrayFromLibtorrentEntry(entry);
}
```

This should be easy to fix, but am I missing something? Am I attempting to save via the wrong mechanism?

Answer (score 4):

libtorrent does not provide a mechanism to save the torrent list. The expectation is that you (the client) keeps the .torrent files on disk (as they are immutable) and just re-add them the first thing you do when starting up again.

The one exception is when adding a magnet link, then you need to be able to turn a torrent_handle into an actual .torrent file. Here's a snippet to do that:

```
boost::intrusive_ptr<torrent_info const> ti = h.torrent_file();
create_torrent new_torrent(*ti);
std::vector<char> out;
bencode(std::back_inserter(out), new_torrent.generate());
save_file("mytorrent.torrent", out);
```

However, perhaps an even better option is to save the .torrent file (or info-dict) as part of the resume data. When calling [`save_resume_data()`](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#save_resume_data()), if you pass in the [`save_info_dict`](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#save_resume_flags_t) flag, the resume data will contain everything you need to restart the torrent. i.e. an actual copy of the .torrent file will be saved inside the resume file.

The example that comes with libtorrent simply keeps .torrent files in a directory, and scans the directory on startup (and periodically), so the filesystem stores the torrent list. A more efficient way of doing it is to store the actual .torrent files along with the resume data in a database (say, sqlite).

Here's an example of saving the resume data bundled with the .torrent file inside a sqlite database.

[save_resume.cpp](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent-webui/blob/master/src/save_resume.cpp), [save_resume.hpp](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent-webui/blob/master/src/save_resume.hpp)

The database makes for more efficient startup, when loading them all. Bundling the resume data together with the torrent also saves you one disk seek per torrent you load).